# How to design a POST method consuming JSON in JAX-RS web service?

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, curl

I'm designing a simple **REST API** and I got ***GET*** methods working OK, however I can't get the ***POST*** methods working properly.

```
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response nuevaCancion(Cancion cancion) {

        Response response = Response.ok().build();
        Response negativeResponse = Response.notAcceptable(null).build();
        return new ConectorCliente("usr", "pass", "REST").insertarCancion(cancion) ? response : negativeResponse;
    }
```

So my method receives a `Cancion` class (class already got `@XmlRootElement` annotation) instance which is supposed to be in JSON format, if everything's ok with the data in the JSON it'll return a **`200`** code and a **`406 Not Acceptable`** code.

I'm trying to test the method by this curl statement:

```
curl -X POST -d @cancion.json http://localhost:8080/REST/webresources/canciones --header "Content-Type:application/json"
```

where cancion.json is a file containing a proper JSON representation of a `Cancion` instance.

However I'm getting a `HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type` code. Also staying: *The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.*

I'm using Tomcat as server and Jersey and Jackson libraries for REST. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Looks like your server isn't deserializing the JSON string into a valid `Cancion` object, thus getting yout error.

Comment: Of course, looks like that. I *just* need to know the *why*

Comment: @diegoaguilar, did you resolve the problem?  If so how did you resolve it, was the problem due to a jar file? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I couldn't @Byron and as it was for learning purposes I gave up then. I thought then I should write whole code myself ( I was using NetBeans and some template code are added automatically) if you find a solution please tell me.